# PHP get next/previous record from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I working on a website, which works like a blog. In this blog, there are articles (I add them ot another admins) and these articles have sections. I want that, when user is reading any post, that above the post, there will be 2 buttons: `previous article` and `next article`. There is MySQL database, which looks like this (`parent` is `id` of section):

```
+------+-------+---------+--------+
| id   | title | content | parent | etc...
+------+-------+---------+--------+
| 1    | test1 | ...     | 2      |
| 2    | test2 | ...     | 4      |
| 3    | test3 | ...     | 2      |
| 4    | test4 | ...     | 1      |
| 5    | test5 | ...     | 2      |
+------+-------+---------+--------+
```

Now, for example, user is reading `test3` and I want, that it will return me ids `1` and `5`, because `test1` is previous article with same `parent` and `test5` is next article with same `parent`.

What should I do, to get result like this?

Comment: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#75

Comment: You're... basing this on `id`? In short: you either _never_ change the order (can be valid, but limits your options), or you change id's around (a _very_ big nono...). But: it's a `SELECT * FROM table WHERE parent_id = <current_parent_id> AND id < <current_id> ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` for the previous, and `SELECT * FROM table WHERE parent_id = <current_parent_id> AND id > <current_id> ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;` for the next.

Comment: Yes @Wrikken, that is what I wanted! Also thanks Dagon, it is useful.

Comment: You're probably best to use pagination, instead of relying on a single single, whether going up or down a single level/number at a time.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: depends highly on the use case. In this case, for blogs, you may have a point, it kind of depends on how long the articles are, and if only one level should be shown on next/previous or can also mean another level/parent if at the end/start.

Comment: @Wrikken If records are fixed and do not stand to increase, then the accepted answer is good. However, databases were meant/conceived to add records, therefore pagination would be more suitable. Least, that's what I would choose to do and to look ahead for potential records addition(s).

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Hm, how do you mean? I would never sort on `id` like here, _but_: I fail to see why having a large single-item page, with previous/next buttons, prevents one from adding records in a way that pagination wouldn't...

Comment: @Wrikken Doing `WHERE id < currentID where parent = 2` and `WHERE id > currentID where parent = 2` that only covers one step up or down. OP would constantly need to change that condition if fetching another record, wouldn't you agree? Or, is there something I may have missed/misunderstood?

Comment: If all these items are on a single page, you'd query what the next & previous links are on loading/creating, and link the them directly by id. So: every single pageload has completely the same logic, there's no altering. It does require 3 queries per page yes: one for the current record, on for the previous, one for the next, but if they can use indexes, the difference between that and sorting bigger portions is neglible. Furthermore: as those links are straight by id, you don't have to deal with the the SEO problem that an article on ?page=3 is suddenly on ?page=4 after some changes in order.

Comment: The answer that I accepted is right, `id`s in my database are just auto_incremental integers for purposes like this. Articles won't change its `id`/position, because they are sorted by creation date. Each article has custom `page_url` value, which is created on creation from title and this is how I access them. I edited that queries little to fit my options, all I wanted was idea to start :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the query for the previous article:

```
SELECT id  FROM article WHERE id < currentID AND parent = 2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

the query for the next article:

```
SELECT id  FROM article WHERE id > currentID AND parent = 2 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You had ther `WHERE` two times and for previous article there should be DESC ordering, because when there are 3 articles with lower `id` that current one, it will return the first one, not actually previous one.

Comment: Replace the second where with an AND

Comment: boys, you are correct, but the query was just exemplary comparing the two queries

Comment: @ratlab it's not about you, it's about newbies who can just copy/paste the code to their projects and get exceptions/errors.... That's why even simple examples should be correct